# Has "crescent-twinkling" even been demonstrated or at least calculated/predicted? Any "twinkleometer" data for Venus out there?

Tags: observational-astronomy, amateur-observing, venus, atmospheric-effects, resource-request

[My new answer to *Why does Venus flicker?*](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/50982/7982) addresses something that I find particularly interesting; Venus can be an incredibly thin crescent at times, and even a 1 arcminute large thin ring with an edge width of only one or two arcseconds (see below).

This suggests to me that Venus can twinkle much more like a star than a filled-disk planet at certain times. So for example in a comment there I wrote:

> I have a strong hunch that if Jupiter were sitting right next to Venus on 12 April 2015 it would not have twinkled to the same extent.

@ProfRob notes that it turns out that Venus was a large-ish 15 arcecond disk 75% illuminated on 12 April 2015 so "crescent-twinkling" wasn't the reason that Venus twinkled for the OP on that day.

But I'm still convinced that it's gotta be a real, measurable phenomenon if there is such a thing as a planet "twinkleometer" and it's been applied systematically to Venus.

So I'd like to ask:

**Question:** Has "crescent-twinkling" even been demonstrated or at least calculated/predicted? Any "twinkleometer" data out there?

---

For more on how Venus's dance changes distance from Earth and illuminated fraction in such a way that it's almost always between -3.8 and -4.8 magnitude, see answers to

- [Venus' magnitude during inferior conjunction](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/33797/7982)

---

From the linked answer:

> [image: Phases of Venus, from https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Phases_Venus.jpg]
>
> **above:** Phases of Venus, originally from [Wikimedia](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Phases_Venus.jpg) but annotated.
>
> For three times in 2004 (Feb 27, May 7, and June 8) I've taken the angular diameters of Venus from [JPL's Horizons](https://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/horizons/app.html#/) and using the largest (June 8) as a calibration for the image shown the full diameter of Venus.
>
> Then I've drawn a thin rectangle to eyeball the width of the bright part of the limb that would contribute most of the light. The annotated numbers (15/5, 40/3, 58/1) are the apparent diameters of the full disk and the width of the bright limb *in arcseconds*.

Comment: Note: as I've commented [elsewhere](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/113867): "The same localized random phenomenon in the upper atmosphere that makes an object of ~arcsec extent in 2 dimensions twinkle must also make an object of ~arcsec extent in 1 dimension twinkle, though by a somewhat lesser amount. This is inescapable physics and is not open to debate. What I've asked is if anyone has measured it and/or *formally predicted it* in a rigorous and peer-reviewed way. I've added the [resource-request] tag to the question to make that clearer."